# Hive action fails in Oozie executed from Hue UI

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, oozie

I am executing oozie hive action and it fails in Hue UI with the following exception in Hive logs:

```
2016-07-15 15:27:58,430 ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:138)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 10 more
2016-07-15 15:27:58,432 ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:736)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:138)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 10 more
```

Kerberos is enabled on Hadoop cluster, all the settings are added in hive-site.xml. 
Also I am able to connect to hiveserver2 from command line.

Please help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use plain authentication to connect to a secured environment.

```
Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN
```

I am not sure whether it is the same in HUE, but normally I would suspect that you need to set the hive authentication method to KERBEROS .